# Jasmine unit test for the following function in my angularjs controller. I am using TS with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-services

```
 public getTxFilterData(): any {
        this.txRejectsService.showLoader = true;
        var momentObj: moment.MomentStatic = moment;
        this.$http({
            url: txRejectsReadApi,
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                startDate: momentObj(this.selectedStartDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
                endDate: momentObj(this.selectedEndDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
                sourceSystem: this.selectedSourceSystem.Name || '',
                eventType: this.selectedEventType.Id || ''
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            var localTxData = this.convertUTCDateTimeToLocal(response.data);
            this.populateGridData(localTxData);
            this.txRowSelected = false;
            this.txRejectsService.showLoader = false;
        }, (error) => {
             this.notificationService.error({
                 message: "Failed to load data. Try again."
             });
            this.txRejectsService.showLoader = false;
            this.$log.error(`error ${error}`);
            this.$log.info(error);
        })
    }
```

I want to specifically test the .then() block and error() block of the $http inside the function. I am new to unit testing using Jasmine, apology for any errors.

Comment: you should start asking google, or get simple example working in github, or check youtube for video lectures, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=angular+1+testing+http+get

Comment: basically there is $http analog in testing called $httpBackend, you say, on getting that api address, return me that result, flush $httpBackend and check result